# Android Zoom level get back to static zoom level and camera gets back to current location every second

Tags: android, google-maps, maps

Basically I want to allow the user to change zoom level so that user can zoom in out but the camera rapidly gets back to original zoom level, secondly i am unable to move the camera it gets back to current location.
Here is my code

```
mLocation = location;
LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(11));
```

Comment: are you writing this code in onlocationchanged method, please check as that method will call frequently.

Comment: Yes I am writing this code in onlocationchanged

Comment: you can use above method in onmapready method.